# getting 400 Bad Request error frequently when trying to use flask-socket with uwsgi and nginx

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I have a flask app running with Flask-SocketIO on port 5000.

I am using uwsgi to run this app on the production server.

This is my uwsgi .ini file for the app:

```
[uwsgi]
module = server.webserver:app
callable =  app

master = true
processes = 5

http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5000

die-on-term = true
plugin = python35

#chdir = /var/xyz/webapp
wsgi-file = /var/xyz/webapp/server/webserver.py
virtualenv = /opt/venv3
#home = /opt/venv3/bin
gevent = 1000
enable-threads = true
```

And I am using nginx as reverse proxy to this app & my nginx server block is :

```
 server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        client_body_timeout 15s;
        client_header_timeout 15s;

        server_name x.y.z;

        root /var/xyz/webapp;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location /{
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_redirect  off;

            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /socket.io {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/socket.io;
        }
 }
```

Now every time the client tries to connect to the socket the request gets 400 Bad Request Error frequently. But if I comment these lines from my uwsgi .ini file:

```
#master = true
#processes = 5
```

the socket gets connected and runs normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a little bit late however I believe it has to do with the processes = 5 portion.  Per the dev at this [link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/631#issuecomment-362927945) Nginx should be setup to do load balancing multiple processes across socket servers.  This is more to help anyone else that stumbles across this.  Flask-SocketIO imo is incredibly difficult to configure properly.  Load balancing multiple servers is easy enough in Nginx though.  It is as simple as binding the flask app to a new port (5001, 5002 etc) and adding the nodes with the uWSGI apps as nodes to Nginx.

More details can be found at this [link](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#uwsgi-web-server) as they explain it better